# Binding DataGridComboBoxColumn with model

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, datagridcomboboxcolumn

I create WPF application with Entity Framework(code first) .I have this model

```
public class Person 
{
   public int Id {get; set;}
   public string Name {get; set;}
   public virtual Country Country {get ;set;}
}

public class Country
{

   public int Id {get; set;}
   public string Name {get; set;}
}
```

I want to display the information from Person in the DataGrid - name person and name country. Display the name of the country does not work. I have tried several options, this latest, but name of county not display.

```
 <DataGrid name ="gridPerson" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
                        <DataGrid.Columns>
                            <DataGridTextColumn 
                                                Binding="{Binding Name}"
                                                Header="Person Name" />
                            <DataGridComboBoxColumn 
                                                    Header="CountryName" 
                                                    SelectedItemBinding="{Binding                                                              County}"
                                                    SelectedValueBinding="{Binding                                                              Path=Id}"
                                                    SelectedValuePath="Name" />

                        </DataGrid.Columns>
           </DataGrid>
```

code behind

```
    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        personContext = new PersonContext();
        personContext.Persons.Load();
        personContext.Counties.Load();
        gridPerson.ItemSource = personContext.Persons.local; 
    }

    public class PersonContext : DbContext
    {

       public DbSet<Person> Persons { get; set; } 
       public DbSet<Country> Countries { get; set; }
    }
```

How to display the name of the country from my model in the DataGridComboBoxColumn?

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify `DisplayMemberPath` for the ComboBox.

```
<DataGrid name ="gridPerson" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
     <DataGrid.Columns>
         <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Name}" Header="Person Name" />
         <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="CountryName" SelectedItemBinding="{Binding County}" SelectedValueBinding="{Binding Path=Id}" SelectedValuePath="Name" DisplayMemberPath="Name" />
     </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo:

```
SelectedItemBinding="{Binding County}"
```

Should be:

```
SelectedItemBinding="{Binding Country}"
```

Watch for binding errors in the Output window!